# React - How to avoid assigning fallback value while loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that renders based on condition.

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div>
   {isFruit ? 'Mango' : 'Onion'}
  </div>
}
```

The problem is that `isFruit` is fetched from an API, so it's `undefined` for some time.

While its `undefined`, the component renders with `Onion` (incorrectly), then updates with `Mango` when `isFruit` is fetched.

I want to *defer* the component render if `isFruit` value is `undefined`. Is there a way to do that? Or some other way to not show `Onion` during the API call.

Comment: Check if it’s undefined and don’t show anything at that point?

Comment: What should it show when `isFruit` is undefined?

Comment: You also need to make up your mind about where to store the state, to make sure that `MyComponent` is updated when `isFruit` changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could return an empty component if `isFruit` is `undefined`

```
function MyComponent() {
    if (isFruit === undefined) return <></>

    return <div>
    {isFruit ? 'Mango' : 'Onion'}
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a loading state to manage the wait time for api call.
You will have to set loading to true when api call is triggered and set it back to false as soon as API call gets completed(failed or succeeded).This implementation can be handled like below:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(url).then((res)=>{
      //.... code here
      setLoading(false)
    }).catch((err)=>{
      //... err handling here
      setLoading(false)
    })
  },[])
  return <div>
  {
      loading ? <Loader /> : isFruit ? 'Mango' : 'Onion'
  }
  </div>
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, it would be better if `loading` state is set to `true` by default, otherwise it would still render "Onion" for a bit.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for noticing it.